Getting com.drew.imaging.ImageProcessingException: File format is not supported on MP4, MOV, QT and 3GP video files
Using metadata-extractor-2.19.0.jar, this code:
Metadata metadata = null;

try {
    metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata( pathSourceFile.toFile() );
} 
catch(ImageProcessingException ipe) {
    System.out.println("The following exception occured while attempting to read metadata from " + pathSourceFile.toString());
    ipe.printStackTrace(System.out);
    throw ipe;
}

throws ImageProcessingException: File format is not supported when input is an MP4, QT, MOV or 3gp file.  Here's an example:
The following exception occured while attempting to read metadata from C:\Test Input\Borg.mp4
com.drew.imaging.ImageProcessingException: File format is not supported
    at com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(ImageMetadataReader.java:146)
    at com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(ImageMetadataReader.java:162)
    at com.mbm.mediaorganizer.DirectoryNameBuilder.getTags(DirectoryNameBuilder.java:182)
    at com.mbm.mediaorganizer.DirectoryNameBuilder.getDirectoryName(DirectoryNameBuilder.java:61)
    at com.mbm.mediaorganizer.RelocateFileVisitor.relocateFile(RelocateFileVisitor.java:114)
    at com.mbm.mediaorganizer.RelocateFileVisitor.visitFile(RelocateFileVisitor.java:96)
    at com.mbm.mediaorganizer.RelocateFileVisitor.visitFile(RelocateFileVisitor.java:1)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2811)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2882)
    at com.mbm.mediaorganizer.MediaOrganizer.run(MediaOrganizer.java:126)
    at com.mbm.mediaorganizer.MediaOrganizer.main(MediaOrganizer.java:40)

And here's what Mediainfo says about the MP4 file:
General
Complete name                            : C:\Test Input\Borg.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42 (mp42/mp41)
File size                                : 171 MiB
Duration                                 : 1 min 40 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 14.3 Mb/s
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-07-28 20:50:07
Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-07-28 20:50:41
©TIM                                     : 00:00:00:00
©TSC                                     : 30000
©TSZ                                     : 1001

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.2
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, RefFrames               : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 1 min 40 s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 13.9 Mb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 16.0 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 29.970 (30000/1001) FPS
Standard                                 : NTSC
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.224
Stream size                              : 167 MiB (98%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-07-28 20:50:07
Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-07-28 20:50:07
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 1 min 40 s
Source duration                          : 1 min 40 s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 317 kb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 349 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 3.80 MiB (2%)
Source stream size                       : 3.80 MiB (2%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-07-28 20:50:07
Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-07-28 20:50:07

Why am I getting ImageProcessingException: File format is not supported?

You are using an image reader for movies, for mp4 use Mp4MetadataReader etc...

Not according to the project web site: https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor.  It states it supports MP4 and QuickTime.

Yes, it's an unfortunate quirk of history that the class is named that. Nowadays it supports video and audio.

There's not enough information here to say why that file is not supported. Can you file an issue on https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor and attach a sample file? Without a sample file it's difficult to say why it's not supported.
